# C#: Создание формы подключения (входа) к БД MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server

На стороне сервера БД определены 2 типа пользователей: с правами редактирования и с правами только для чтения. Для них установлены соответствующие логин и пароль.
Каким образом можно реализовать форму входа, чтобы при запуске приложения для пользователя появилось диалоговое окно, где он может ввести свой логин, пароль и подключиться к БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так: вот у Вас есть форма. На ней есть текстовые поля, в которые пользователь вводит свои логин и пароль. Пусть это tbLogin и tbPassword.

Также, допустим, у нас есть кнопка, которая вызывает процедуру проверки подключения.

Для подключения к БД используется так называемая connection string, куда мы поместим эти данные.

Тогда код, который будет выполнять проверку (для MS SQL Server), может быть примерно таким:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = $"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password={tbPassword.Text};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={tbLogin.Text};Initial Catalog=FsaRobot;Data Source=192.168.0.25";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Not connected, error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Теперь немного расширим наш сценарий.

Пускай у нас будет "форма проверки логина - пароля" и "главная форма".

Главная форма должна запускаться только в том случае, если проверка прошла успешно.

я бы написал такой код следующим образом.

Программы .NET WinForms обычно стартуют из static main() примерно так:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace DbExample {
        static class Program {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main() {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
```

Здесь главное - то, что создаётся экземпляр формы Form1 и передаётся в метод Application.Run()

Сделаем, чтобы последовательно создавались две формы, форма логина и главная. В форму логина добавим публичное поле LoginSuccess. И будем в процессе создания форм его проверять:

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace DbExample {
        static class Program {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main() {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                FLogin fl = new FLogin();
                Application.Run(fl);
                if (fl.LoginSuccess){
                    FMain fMain = new FMain();
                    Application.Run(fMain);
                }
                else{
                    MessageBox.Show("Извините, проверка логина-пароля неудачна");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Тогда FMain запустится только в случае удачной проверки логина - пароля.

Саму проверку можно организовать, чуть чуть поменяв первоначальный код под button1 в форме логина:

```
    public bool LoginSuccess=false;

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = $"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password={tbPassword.Text};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={tbLogin.Text};Initial Catalog=FsaRobot;Data Source=192.168.0.25";
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                LoginSuccess = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Not connected, error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        Close();
    }
```

Конечно, здесь код немного упрощен, например, нет обработки ошибок.

(Если у кого то есть критика этого способа - модете написать в комментариях.)

Comment: Попробовал Ваш способ: у меня выдаёт ошибку. Вроде как вместо введённого в поле tbLogin текста отправляется само выражение {tbLogin.Text}

Comment: Я все еще раз проверил... Не скажете, какая версия C# у Вас используется? Не может быть такого, что не работает выражение $"{}" - которое работает начиная с C# 6.0?

Comment: виноват, потерял символ $. Теперь всё работает

Comment: Ну тогда - всё отлично!

Comment: Не подскажите как установить взаимосвязь формы входа с основной формой приложения. Чтобы после того как пользователь всё ввёл он мог работать с БД в основной форме?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, можете попробовать такой способ

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, по поводу добавления публичного поля LoginSuccess. Для меня не совсем очевидно как это сделать

Comment: Дополнил ответ!

Comment: Работает. Но есть но. Логин, пароль вводятся. Форма входа закрывается - открывается основная форма. И как видимо, на этом этапе теряется подключение. Ибо только исполнение кода основной формы доходит до места где DataGrid обращается к БД, выскакивает ошибка: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'При входе в систему пользователя "" произошла ошибка.'

Comment: Ну правильно, у Вас же информация, введенная в форму логина - никуда больше не попадает. а Вам надо connection string использовать в главной форме. Чтобы это сделать - надо её куда то... засунуть. Например, в глобальную статическую переменную, хотя все, кто разбирается в ООП, скажут, что это плохой тон